Biased results from SimPy model of a M/M/s queueing system
I am building a simulation using SimPy and comparing the results to the theoretical calculations in a M/M/s queue model. However, most of the time the simulation yields results about 10% lower than the theoretical values, even though I ran it for an extend period. For example, the theoretical mean waiting time for all customers should be 5.15448, while most of the time the simulation shows a mean waiting time less than 5. And the theoretical mean waiting time for those who actually wait should be 6.0, while the simulation shows a mean waiting time for those who actually wait less than 5.8. This discrepancy suggests potential errors in my code. Could someone help me debug it? Thanks a lot!
import simpy
import numpy as np 

params = {"arrival_rate": 4, "service_rate": (1/2.4), "num_servers": 10, "num_customers": 5000000, "stream_id": 1}
queue_length_list = []  # This list will hold the queue lengths
customer_count_list = []  # This list will hold the number of customers in the system
waiting_time_list = []  # This list will hold the waiting times
utilization_list = []  # This list will hold the utilizations
throughput_list = []  # This list will hold the throughputs

def customer(env, server, params):    
    arrival_time = env.now            
    queue_entry_time = env.now
    with server.request() as request:
        queue_length_list.append((env.now, len(server.queue)))    
        customer_count_list.append((env.now, len(server.queue) +            server.count))    
        queue_entry_time = env.now
        yield request                 
        waiting_time_list.append((env.now, env.now - queue_entry_time))     
        utilization_list.append((env.now, server.count / params["num_servers"]))     
        service_time = np.random.exponential(1.0 / params["service_rate"])     
        yield env.timeout(service_time)
        throughput_list.append((env.now, len(waiting_time_list)/env.now))     

def arrivals(env, server, params):
    for _ in range(params["num_customers"]):
        yield env.timeout(np.random.exponential(1.0 / params["arrival_rate"]))
        env.process(customer(env, server, params))

env = simpy.Environment()
server = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=params["num_servers"]) #
env.process(arrivals(env, server, params))
env.run()

times, waiting_times = zip(*waiting_time_list)
mean_waiting_time = np.mean(waiting_times)
print(f"Mean Waiting Time:", mean_waiting_time)
max_waiting_time = np.max(waiting_times)
print(f"Max Waiting Time:", max_waiting_time)
non_zero_waiting_times = [wt for wt in waiting_times if wt > 0]
if len(non_zero_waiting_times) > 0:
    mean_non_zero_waiting_time = sum(non_zero_waiting_times) / len(non_zero_waiting_times)
    print(f"Mean Non-Zero Waiting Time:", mean_non_zero_waiting_time)
print()

queue_entry_time is a variable which is not necessary in the code. I added it just to check if there would be any differences from the case when I used arrival_time variable only. However, this did not help.

It's quite likely you are experiencing initialization bias. Running your model longer will asymptotically reduce the bias, but to eliminate it you need to truncate some (a priori unknown) amount of the data from the start of the run to eliminate the observations which are influenced by the starting conditions. The best way to do this has been an active research topic for more than 60 years.

Also note that data from queueing systems is serially correlated, which violates the classic assumptions for confidence intervals. You'll need a lot more data than you think, along with some sophisticated techniques, to derive valid interval estimates for the performance measures you're studying.

I'd appreciate another look at my code to see if there are any hidden errors. I'm new to Python and SimPy, and while I see other examples using classes, I believe my approach without a class might be valid in this case. Can you offer some feedback?
